# I need help getting ridding of this weed in my flower garden

Tags: identification, weeds

Can someone identify this weed and tell me how to stop it from coming back?

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more detail please, such as where is it growing, lawn or in open soil? And another photo showing it in situ in the ground so we can see growth habit, height and spread would be very helpful

Comment: Could you add some more photo, one e.g. on garden. It could be a potentilla, e.g. Potentilla reptans. But it is very difficult just by this photo.

Comment: Very difficult from an image this small, @Giacomo is probably along the right lines, but I would start with a more general suggestion that it is probably _Ranunculaceae_